# Identity server 4 .net core InvalidOperationException: RSA key does not have a private key

Tags: rsa, .net-core, windows-server-2008, private-key, identityserver4

i am using Identity server package to build custom Identity provider
when running the server project locally every things OK but when publishing in windows server 2008 R2 i get the below error message

[image]

Comment: do u run locally using VS or dotnet command? My b VS uses self-signed sertificates, wich u dont have on enviroment

Comment: using visual studio locally

Comment: try to publish to some local folder and start using command "dotnet sevicename.dll"